# stringstream.good() > Different behaviour in VS and Eclipse compiler

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio-2005, stringstream

I have some understanding problems regarding the **stringstream**.

**Example:**

```
stringstream stream(commands);

    while (true) {
        string line;
        getline(stream, line);

        if (!stream.good())
            break;
        if (line.size() > 0){
            lines.push_back(line);
        }
        else{
             break;
        }
    }
```

If I use this code in Eclipse it's no problem, it work as expected.
Using this in Vistual Studio 2005 **stream.good()** seems to return always **false**

why?

I would really appreciate some explanation.

Comment: You can take that whole code and replace it with 4 lines doing the same, you know ... http://ideone.com/tLCTl - using .good() is almost never a good idea. Use the stream state, getline returns the stream.

Comment: give me a moment i'm trying to track down another wired c++ thing...

Comment: seems to work.
But I would like to know why the good() method is not good to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To close this Question:**

Like **etarion** said it's just a matter of the `good()` method. Using some other mechanism works fine.
Thanks for your help!